# How to use PyDev in Eclipse Photon?

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, editor

I am running Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) with java 1.8 and I want to install the [PyDev-Plugin](https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html).

After the installation PyDev is not working:

1. No Python Editor available
2. Cannot create new Python files by using `File>New`
3. No entry for PyDev in `Window>Preferences`

**How to use PyDev in Eclipse Photon?**

Comment: The site you link to says Java 11 is required. Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there are any messages.

Comment: Thank you for that hint. I you scroll down in that link it says you need java 8. Seems the upper hint about java 11 is correct.

Comment: Eclipse Photon is 11 releases and a couple of years behind. Did it work with the current version of Eclipse?

Comment: Yes! Upgrading to java11 solved the problem.